# How do I update only one trace in react plotly?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am using react-plotly to generate a large timeline of data (10,000-100,000 points) and I animate across the data in another window. I need to get a scrubber (vertical line) that moves with a react-property representing time, but I need to update the scrubber without updating the rest of the timeline, since it would take so long to do so. How can I get just the vertical line to update?

Edit: Was asked for code

In the following code, the `backtracks` and `thresholds` objects are `Uint32Array`s and represent the y-axis of traces, where the x-axes are the `Uint32Array`s `backtracksTime` and `thresholdsTime`. What I am trying to get is a vertical line at the x-coordinate `currentTime`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Plotly from 'plotly.js';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

import styles from './style.scss';

export default class ThresholdWindow extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    backtracks: PropTypes.object,
    backtracksTime: PropTypes.object,
    thresholds: PropTypes.object,
    thresholdsTime: PropTypes.object,
    currentTime: PropTypes.number,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      plotRevision: 0,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
      const oldPlotRevision = this.state.plotRevision;
      const rect = entries[0].contentRect;
      this.setState({
        plotRevision: oldPlotRevision + 1,
        height: rect.height,
        width: rect.width,
      });
    });
    resizeObserver.observe(this.container);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.plotRevision !== nextState.plotRevision) {
      return true;
    } else if (this.props.currentTime !== nextProps.currentTime) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    const data = [
      {
        name: 'Threshold',
        type: 'scattergl',
        mode: 'lines',
        x: this.props.thresholdsTime,
        y: this.props.thresholds,
        side: 'above',
      },
      {
        name: 'Backtracks',
        type: 'scattergl',
        mode: 'lines',
        x: this.props.backtracksTime,
        y: this.props.backtracks,
      },
      {
        name: 'Current Time',
        type: 'scattergl',
        mode: 'lines',
        x: [this.props.currentTime, this.props.currentTime],
        y: [0, 1],
        yaxis: 'y2',
      },
    ];

    return (
      <div className={styles['threshold-window']} ref={(el) => { this.container = el; }}>
        <Plot
          divId={`backtracks-${this.props.name}`}
          className={styles['threshold-graph']}
          ref={(el) => { this.plot = el; }}
          layout={{
            width: this.state.width,
            height: this.state.height,
            yaxis: {
              fixedrange: true,
            },
            yaxis2: {
              side: 'right',
              range: [0, 1],
            },
            margin: {
              l: 35,
              r: 15,
              b: 20,
              t: 15,
            },
            legend: {
              orientation: 'h',
              y: 1,
            },
          }}
          revision={this.state.plotRevision}
          data={data}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit2: I don't actually see the `currentTime` line anywhere, so I'm pretty sure there's a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

With [`react-plotly.js`](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js) the performance should be decent, as it will only redraw what it needs to.

Comment: I have provided code, but I'm thinking that it's possibly the large diff that is taking time.

Comment: Just to confirm: are you using a version of plotly.js greater than 1.34 ?

Comment: Yup, Plotly.js at 1.35.2 and react-plotly.js at 1.7.0

Comment: It might be useful to know that the property `currentTime` is being updated about 60 times / sec, also on a `window.getAnimationFrame` loop.

Comment: OK. Can I request that you create an issue here https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js for us to continue to exchange on this? StackOverflow isn't great for this sort of back'n'forth and there likely isn't a canonical answer here :)